# creating variables inside functions with python

Tags: python, function

How can I create a variable inside a function and then use that function by importing that script and running that function in a separate script?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: It seems that you need a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: search google 'how to python'.

Answer (score 2):

a.py

```
def function_to_use(data):
    use_var = data
    return use_var
```

b.py

```
from a import function_to_use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print function_to_use(6)
```